# Is there a Dot Net System.Attribute equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, .net, reflection, custom-attributes

Ok. this question goes to all who can program java and .NET.

In .NET there is the class `System.Attribute` which allows the user to extend the reflection information with custom meta info data.

The question: Is there a similar class/mechanism in java and how is it called? Post links to any tutorial, that'd be great!

I need custom meta info for Methods, Classes and method arguments. Is that possible in java?

Comment: You are looking for annotations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html

Comment: Thanks man. Why the expert disliked this question?

Comment: ah i see your changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: This is called annotations in java. (Custom attributes in .net)